# How to list array inside a javascript alert

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings, I want to display the content with some html tags in the alert level.
I tried this:

```js
array = ["toto", "titi"]
alert("*" + array.join('\n'))
```

but the problem here, I got only the first line with *.
how can I resolvr this probleme to show all the lements with * in the begining ?

Comment: Some reserved words (like array or function) are part of JavaScript, including built-in object properties and HTML event listeners. You can't use reserved words as variable name.

Comment: @Wimanicesir just an FYI, `array` is not a reserved word.

Comment: Not explicitly no @evolutionxbox. But is it good practice to also avoid this. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```js
var arrStr =  ["toto","titi"];

alert([''].concat(arrStr).join('\n*').trim());
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Array.map()

You should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create a new array populated with each element having * prefix.

```js
const array = ["foo", "bar"];

alert(array.map(value => `*${value}`).join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Before joining the array you can map it to add `*` in front of each entry with `arrayOfStrings.map(i => '*' + i)`

```js
arrayOfStrings = ["toto", "titi"];

alert(arrayOfStrings.map(i => '*' + i).join('\n'));
```